# What are some non-Greek/Latin hybrid words?

Tags: etymology

Most etymological hybrids in English are a mixture of Greek and Latin. I'm interested in hybrids from other languages, French and German, say.

Can you think of any good examples? I'd be especially interested in modifications which cross languages. For example, if "knifelette" was a word it would be a German root with a French inflection.

The older/more established the better.

Answer (score 1):

etymonline is lovely to click around on for these things...

I found [keynote](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=keynote&allowed_in_frame=0) as a combination of Germanic origin *key* and Latin / French origin *note*, first used in 1783.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot that ultimately happened because of the French influence due to the Norman invasion of England. Beefcake, muttonchops, ... I can't think of any compounds involving French legal terms (mortgage, jury,...), but I'm sure there are some.